# Double slit experiment: Single photons of red light mixed with high intensity infrared light

Tags: photons, double-slit-experiment, interference, thought-experiment

First this is only a presumtion. Let say we fire single photons of red light at the double slit to get a interference pattern on the screen. The distances between frindges would have certain quantities. Now, let them mix with intense infrared light which doesn't produce colored frindges. The only intention is to figure out does the infrared light force the red single photon to choose one of the paths produced by interferention of infrared waves at the slit. I think the single red photon produces a set of paths to the screen that are nothing else but reinforced EM field lines towards the screen but the intense infrared should produce higer values of the field and somehow make that the distances between red frindges at the screen get larger. Is this possibly thrue?

Comment: What direction are the IR photons coming from? Same as the red ones? A diagram might help.

Answer (score 0):

The result will just be the incoherent superposition of the interference patterns of the two lightsources.